# How to use classes?

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm beginner.
I want to read data from csv file.
Part of my code now is:

```
def get_csv_data():
    data = pd.read_csv(CSV_FILE_PATH)
    dict = data.to_dict()
    weekdays_daily_time = float(dict['VALUE'][0])
    weekend_daily_time = float(dict['VALUE'][1])
    booting_time = float(dict['VALUE'][2])
    
    return weekdays_daily_time, weekend_daily_time, booting_time
```

Every time if I wanna use single data (eg. booting_time), I'm calling this function, returning all values and getting single value from output list.
I believe easiest way is to create class, but I can't find how to use it :

I have also another function, currently as well called in full every time, even I want to save just one variable (eg today_used)

```
def get_data_from_domoticz():
    response = reqs.get('http://'+ DOMOTICZSERVER + '/json.htm?type=devices&rid='+IDX)
    response_dict = json.loads(response.text)
    counter_value = int(response_dict["result"][0]["Counter"])
    #get current date from server
    date_from_server = datetime.datetime.strptime(response_dict["ServerTime"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    server_date = date_from_server.date()
    day_of_week = server_date.weekday()
    today_used = int(response_dict["result"][0]["CounterToday"])
    return day_of_week, counter_value, server_date, today_used
```

Both functions working right now, but I believe that I should use classes instead and call just one single element.
I understand why classes are used, but I don't really know how and when use it.

I'm expecting results like:

- `get_csv_data.booting_time` ==> returning booting time value from csv file
- `get_csv_data.weekend_daily_time` ==> returning weekend daily time value from csv file
- `get_data_from_domoticz.counter_value` ==> returning counter value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to create data classes to hold the data you've fetched from a file/API call. The most basic way to define such classes in Python would be as follows:

```py
class MyCSVData:
    def __init__(self, weekdays_daily_time, weekend_daily_time, booting_time):
        self.weekdays_daily_time = weekdays_daily_time
        self.weekend_daily_time = weekend_daily_time
        self.booting_time = booting_time
```

The pattern is fairly simple, pick a descriptive name for your class, then have the `__init__` method take in all the data you wish to hold as parameters, and inside the method body have `self.property_name = argument_name`. The property name and argument names don't have to match, but making it so can help with readability.

Now you can modify your functions to return objects, i.e. instantiations of the classes you defined. In your example, it would look as follows:

```py
def get_csv_data():
    data = pd.read_csv(CSV_FILE_PATH)
    dict = data.to_dict()
    weekdays_daily_time = float(dict['VALUE'][0])
    weekend_daily_time = float(dict['VALUE'][1])
    booting_time = float(dict['VALUE'][2])
    
    return MyCSVData(weekdays_daily_time, weekend_daily_time, booting_time)
```

Now the code that calls `get_csv_data` will get back an instance of `MyCSVData`, which can be passed around in your code as needed, and properties can be accessed using the dot operator.

```py
my_csv_data = get_csv_data()

# access weekdays_daily_time without recalling get_csv_data
my_csv_data.weekdays_daily_time
```

You can follow the same pattern for your `get_data_from_domoticz` function.

There are more advanced patterns that can be applied to address your question, depending on the exact context of your problem (e.g. when accessing the data from distant parts of the codebase, or needing to refetch the data from the API every so often).

Comment: Thx!
I've made a screen time app, to check and control kids screen time. I did it, as I can't find app where I can set time limit eg shared for weekdays (eg instead of 1hr daily limit, I wanna set 5hrs limit for Mo-Fri).
For test purposes I don't need to change it remotely - for now I wanna read allowed time from csv, send usage to domoticz (as I have domoticz server running in my network) and save remaining time / last usage date etc to csv (to compare it when program starting, as program never ends - is killed with shutdown and starting as service with windows).

Comment: I wanna make a code most efficient and easy readable (what I see, it's easy for me to make a mistake with variables inside and outside functions) - so I really appreciate for any tips how to improve or organize my code (it's not important for that small app, but I want to learn good practices for larger projects. Is it the best way to use classes? Or maybe you are practicing another way of organizing code?

Answer (score 1):

Using a class allows you to encapsulate multiple (usually related) variables.

Let's say you have a CSV file and there are just 3 specific items that you want. You may want to access the same data multiple times. You may want to consider a "lazy" load of the CSV file.

Try something like this:

```
import pandas

CSV_FILE_PATH = 'your_path_goes_here'

class CSVData:
    def __init__(self, filename: str):
        self._filename = filename
        self._dict = None
        self._values = None
    @property
    def weekdays_daily_time(self) -> float:
        return self.values[0]
    @property
    def weekend_daily_time(self) -> float:
        return self.values[1]
    @property
    def booting_time(self) -> float:
        return self.values[2]
    @property
    def dict(self) -> dict:
        if self._dict is None:
            self._dict = pandas.read_csv(self._filename).to_dict()
        return self._dict
    @property
    def values(self) -> list[float]:
        if self._values is None:
            self._values = [float(v) for v in self.dict['VALUE']]
        return self._values

csvData = CSVData(CSV_FILE_PATH)

print(csvData.weekdays_daily_time)
print(csvData.weekend_daily_time)
print(csvData.booting_time)
```